# Bootstrap accordion with Read more/less

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap accordion feature Read more/less on the content. I need to have at least the first paragraph shown for each accordion item.

When the item is collapsed the button should show Read more and when is expanded it should show Read less.

This is what I am getting at the moment: [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/5AmH7yriGB)

As you can see the first item is expanded and the button should show Read less.

Any ideas how I could achieve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the $this.text('See Less'); and $this.text('See More'); in your JS file.

Edit:

To add on to that - swapping those two in your JS file will only make it so that your first accordion button text look fine. Your second accordion is still botched up. Also, it seems as if you did copy paste the code (for the most part) from the bootstrap docs. If you click on the headings, you'll see that your buttons won't properly update, so you're going to want to look into that too. Your buttons are also only toggling the panel, as opposed to actually functioning like an accordion (i.e., opening up one panel will close the other one that was open). If the 'Show More/Less' buttons aren't really necessary, I'd just go with dumping those and sticking with clicking the headers to open different panels.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply but unfortunately that didn't work. The button is not showing Read less. And how I could show the first paragraph on collapsed item?

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/5AmH7yriGB#

Forgot to say that you'll have to also change the button text for your first accordion section - you have it set to 'Show More', and toggle it accordingly, but the first panel is open upon first visit (so it should make more sense to have that button set to Show Less, at least initially). However, if you start clicking the second panel, you'll notice that your second button will start having that mismatched more/less button problem.

Comment: This is easily solved by using a different class for your second button+accordion, and making another function in your JS to handle that - but that is obviously not very DRY. Sadly, I can't think of a way to fix this, at least, not with purely JS+HTML. If you know some Angular, this is an easy solution.

Comment: (Sorry for the spam of comments, going over character count :x)
In regards to showing the first paragraph on a collapsed item, you can simply put whatever you want to show within the panel-heading div, although I don't know if that's what you want specifically.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. Regarding the first paragraph I've already thought about doing that but the website content comes from the database so that solution won't work in this case. I'm wondering if there is any jquery/javascript plugin that could handle that.

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/EpeGfXaEG4

No idea if you'll like this, it's a pretty meh solution, but it does manage to get your text to show properly. Also went ahead and took off the class="collapse" from your accordion headers. There might be some sort of plugin that can handle this, but I haven't come across any yet (I'm pretty new to JS, though, so that doesn't account for much :P)

Comment: Thank you athoi. I managed solving this by getting rid of the tabs and using a Read more/less plugin in javascript. There was no sense to use both accordion and Read more for this case.

Appreciated all your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a show more/less without using javascript, just a little CSS and html;

HTML:

```
<div id="descriptionContent" class="collapse descriptionText">
                <p><!--Your content--></p>
            </div>
            <a href="#descriptionContent" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed">
                <span class="text-danger readMore">(read more)</span>
                <span class="text-danger readLess">(read less)</span>
            </a>
```

CSS:

```
a .readMore {
    display: none;
}

a .readLess {
    display: inline;
}

a.collapsed .readMore {
    display: inline;
}

a.collapsed .readLess {
    display: none;
}

.descriptionText:not(.in) {
    min-height: 4.25em;
    height: 4.25em;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```